# Do Adaptive shields adapt to non-elemental damage?

Tags: borderlands-2

Adaptive shields adapt to the last "elemental" type they were hit with with a set % of resistance. Sometimes non-elemental is counted as an "element" for resistance/bonuses, so I'm wondering if non-elemental damage is adapted to as well.

If it doesn't protect against non-elemental damage, if I get hit by a non-elemental effect after a fire effect, is my shield still protecting me against fire or does it reset until I get hit by a "real" elemental type again?

Comment: I used one for a bit but couldn't tell.

Comment: It doesn't grant damage resistance, as @feeble said, but resistance to a certain % includin explosion, corrosive, fire, slag, and damn.....what was the last one again?

Comment: Oh that's right......EXPLOSIONSSSS

Comment: @Retrosaur You said Explosions twice, it's shock ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't.

What happens is if the shield is not hit with any other elemental damage (Slag, Corrosive, Fire, Shock or Explosive), it acts exactly like a normal shield and takes normal damage.

If you take damage from a rocket it is counted as normal - so be careful around rockets.

Also if you have health issues (and that's why you're using adaptive shields) try transfusion MIRV grenades - they are lifesavers.

Comment: The point of collaborative editing is to improve your posts.  We're not changing the meaning of it, but trying to make it better.  You should not be using your posts to address the changes @Robotnik made, but perhaps a comment.  I've rolled back your edit as it didn't add anything to your answer.

Comment: I'm not going out of my way to single you out, you know. There are algorithms in place to determine the quality of a post based on length, grammar and spelling mistakes. Any post deemed 'low quality' ends up in the review queue for people like myself and @fbueckert to look at and see if we can improve it. I just happened to notice that I'd edited 4 of your posts in a row, hence my [comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112569/is-it-a-glitch-that-all-three-legs-of-blue-were-broken-simultaneously-and-it-sti/121175#comment163632_121175) on your other post.

Comment: Oh okay sorry about the confusion I thought you were doing it to try and be funny so once again sorry

Comment: @DeathDealer - No harm done. I apologise as well for any confusion I caused :)

Answer (score -1):

They adapt to the last element they were hit with and you're asking if they adapt to NON-elemental damage. Your question is a paradox. No, the shield that helps resist element damage will not resist damage that is NOT an element. if you get hit by a non-elemental damage nothing will change, you will take damage and your shield will continue to resist the previous element it was hit by. It won't reset or anything of that sort. The only thing that can increase non-elemental damage resistance are those artifacts you mentioned (also, artifacts adding to that resistance are quite rare, hold onto them when you find them).

Comment: "Non-elemental" is very often treated as an element in games...including this one, where "elemental resist" relics often come with "non-elemental" as a resist type

Comment: Yes. I know. That's why I said elemental resist relics are the only thing that can increase the non-elemental resistance. You might have seen where I said it, right above this comment.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer?  essentially all feeble is saying is that no, it doesnt accept nonelemental damage

Comment: @Retrosaur I'd say what's wrong is he's saying the question itself contains an answer, and then mentions an exception to that logic himself. Totally correct facts, but somewhat insulting logic.