# Is it a glitch that all three legs of Blue were broken simultaneously and it still lived?

Tags: borderlands-2

**EDIT: Since people are still answering this, the bug seems to have been caused by a health increase in the patch around that time and has since been fixed.**

I know Blue regenerates. We took care of this by having each of us attack one leg, with the siren behind for rezzes. Also, I hit it with about 16 bonus packages (gunzerker). All three legs were bare for about five seconds, but Blue didn't go down, he still had about 1/16 of his health. It was late so we haven't popped back in for a rematch. All other playthroughs I've been in, Blue's been easy enough to kill before any regeneration can occur.

Is this a glitch, or is it possible to still beat Blue when this happens? We hit it with every element, however we could, and not a thing. As far as I know, they only take damage on the crystals, so I expected that to not work.

**Edit:** The lowest Blue's health went was the same each time, as we did break all the leg crystals multiple times. We started just meleeing, as Blue usually is easy with four people. I never saw Blue's health go back to full, now that I think of it, and we let it regenerate for a while at one point.

Comment: I have no idea if it is a glitch, but the only way I could kill him was with close combat attacks. Those are super effective on the legs.

Comment: Tried that too. In fact, that was the first thing I always do with crystalisks. (Although the Bonus Package also seems super effective, and in effect gets all legs at once, as explosive is also good for crystalisks.)

Comment: The only way I ever killed him was running at him and close combatting the legs asap. Any other ways always resulting in what you experienced and I could not destroy it.

Comment: @Ids - It shouldn't be unkillable if you don't start with melees. Also, we started with melees, so that's not it. Nor should it be unkillable after the first regen. This is a bug. I'm glad I'm not the only one to encounter it though.

Comment: Times it was unkillable for me was when I tried to shoot it. But ymmv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blue's health was sort of recently increased with a patch; I suppose it's possible that introduced a glitch where he can have more health than destroying his crystals will reduce.

However in addition to his health restoring, the crystals on this legs will also regrow [after a minute or two](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Blue), adding back 30% of his health. Presumably waiting for his crystals to grow back will let you kill him.

I *do* believe it's a bug that you saw, he definitely can and is supposed to die when all three legs are "broken" and has died like that for me several times (there's even a challenge for killing him before his leg crystals respawn). But since his legs regrowing restores less than 1/3rd of his health I assume that by destroying them you'll eventually whittle him down but I have not personally seen him survive all three legs breaking. Like all crystalisks he doesn't have any weak points but his legs.

Comment: The lowest his health went was the same each time. I probably should have specified that. His health didn't go back to full when we let him sit for a while, so I'm thinking some of the game's maths got confused with the patch. The health increase is probably the culprit.

Comment: @Poik oh, huh. Yeah in that case I'd quit and reload the area and see if it happens again, definitely a bug

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm at work. I'll give an update when I can back to the game.

Comment: Came back with only two players, and killed it before any regeneration occurred. May try and find out if the bug is repeatable, but not right now. I'd say reloading the area is the right fix for now, though.

Answer (score 2):

Blue was not dying even at zero crystals for me on UVHM.  I died, came back and decided to use my RESOLUTE HAIL assault weapon (rains down bullets from above) and that killed him in about 20 seconds.  I'm thinking there's one crystal still on him that you can't target at ground level or something, because raining down bullets melted him fast.

Comment: Huh. May try if this ever happens to me. Hail used to be my favorite gun, I should get a level cap one. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

You can deafeat blue without breaking the leg crystals. Just use torgue or explosive weapons on the main body of blue. I did it alone at level 64, level 66 blue. If you want to speed up the process get his legs low without breaking them and when you've got him down to about 1/6th of his hp, break his legs to deal that last bit of damage. Just remember this one fact, "you can deal damage to blue by attacking his main body with explosive weapons."

Comment: You missed the part where I hit blue with 24 10x Homing Bonus Packages. Which is both explosive, and Torgue. Thank you for your response, but I bet you the glitch was fixed. I will now flag this for locking or deletion due to being no longer relevant.

The time I experienced this, explosive damage on the body did no damage whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested strategy:

1. Get each leg low but not broken
2. Break all the legs in succession
3. Fire explosives at the remaining main body

Things to know:

- Each leg can take away up to 30% of his hp, NOT 1/3 of his life
- After breaking, each leg regenerates ~1 minute later, healing back the 30% hp
- You can technically kill him with just explosives to his main body, he doesn't seem to heal back the damage dealt this way

I have only done this in ultimate vault hunter mode (playthrough 3+). I have not tested it in true vault hunter or normal. I can only assume its the same. Good luck vault hunters.
7/10/2014

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a glitch. In fact, It happens a lot because he is simply a tank.

You're best hitting him with regular or explosive rounds - corrosive does almost nothing. When his legs are out of crit shots use a Rocket Launcher. Also try using more aggressive weapons and leveling some more before facing him, it's a lot easier to take him on when you're the same or a greater level then he is.

Also, take your time through the game. It helps with loot and killing enemies.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! :). I don't usually say this, but this is the third post of yours I've edited today - In future, do you think you could add a little grammar, and focus a bit more on your coherency?

Comment: Well, when I played, after his crystals were gone, he took no damage. I believe I specified in one of my comments that I unloaded a Gunzerker's Double Your Fun plus Stockpile Relic full stash of Bonus Package grenades on him, so 24 grenades x10 + x10 on the second hit. The first two destroyed all of the crystals, and the 22 others did nothing. Just for a little clarification. Thank you for your input. I was on a team of four, all at level with Blue, so that wasn't it. Frankly, I'm still convinced it was a seldom seen glitch I haven't been able to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem on my first second Playthrough after entering True Vault Hunter Mode. However I then went and tried with a bladed weapon, in my case 'Law' (randomised prefix), and I killed a level 43 Blue with no problem.

Answer (score -1):

That's been happening to me all day! We seriously just spent 30 or more minutes trying to figure out what we were doing wrong. We tried reloading the area... but that didn't even work. At some point while punching his legs, I jumped and got on top of his leg and was able to walk up him. Then his death sequence happened and I could finish my quest.